# VBA New Excel.Application is nothing

Tags: excel, vba

I am using following VBA code in Excel 2010 in a button click event:

```
Dim objExcel as Object
Set objExcel - New Excel.Application
```

and used that instance `objExcel` in subsequent code.

This code is very simple and working in most of the computers I have tested including my computer. Whereas in some computers, that instance is not creating. `objExcel` is `Nothing` after the line is executed. So after the line of code is run, `objExcel` is `Nothing`. That is why subsequent codes are failing to execute.
I also tried following code:

```
Set objExcel=CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```

This also has same problem.

All machines have MS Office 2010 installed.
Problem is not due to large number of Excel instances Problematic computers cannot run the code even once.

Should I check or register any component which may cause the problem?

Comment: So you don't get an error, but you don't get a result either? (You definitely mean `Set objExcel = New Excel.Application`, he)

Comment: Does it also occur with `CreateObject("Word.Application")` ?

Comment: I assume you mean `Set objExcel = New Excel.Application` ... with a `=` and not just a dash

Comment: are you starting this out of the Excel VBE or some another VBE (i.e. Access or Word)? If you are not in the Excel VBE, check that you have the appropriate refrences set for Excel under Tools>Reference

Comment: Is there a reason that are not using early binding and `Dim objExcel As Excel.Application`?

Comment: Why are you creating an Excel.Application object within Excel? Usually, this line is used from external Office programs (i.e., Access, Word, PowerPoint). Any of the Excel methods (i.e., Workbooks.Open, Workbooks.ExportAsFixedFormat) can be called directly. Please show us more the processing code.

Comment: @rohrl77 Yes, it is a "=" . I am trying to open new Excel Application from another Excel only.

Comment: @Parfait, I just need to open another Excel macro enabled workbook from a network drive. I used "Workbooks.Open" earlier. But I do not know why, that was making the application badly unresponsive. So I changed the code and used a new excel application instance each time. We do not need to close the application by code, as they are closed by user. code is like below:  **Dim objExcel as Object  Set objExcel = New Excel.Application  objExcel.Workbooks.Open (selectedfile)  objExcel.Visible = True**

Comment: @DirkHorsten Problem is only with Excel. I tried opening Word application from Excel VBE, it is working fine. I tried opening Excel application from Word VBE, it did not work. Do you think there is any problem with MS Excel library 14?